# How to work with 2 category templates in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, categories

I want to have 2 template categories in prestashop. I think it's possible in controller category

```
if ($category->id == 3){
  $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category2.tpl');
} else {
  $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category.tpl');
}
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

Yes this is possible here is the override to put in Override / Controller / front / CategoryController

```
    <?php
class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

    if ($this->category->id == 3) {
          $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category2.tpl');
    } else {            
          $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category.tpl');
    }

    if (!$this->customer_access)
        return;

    if (isset($this->context->cookie->id_compare))
        $this->context->smarty->assign('compareProducts', CompareProduct::getCompareProducts((int)$this->context->cookie->id_compare));

    $this->productSort(); // Product sort must be called before assignProductList()

    $this->assignScenes();
    $this->assignSubcategories();
    $this->assignProductList();

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'category' => $this->category,
        'description_short' => Tools::truncateString($this->category->description, 350),
        'products' => (isset($this->cat_products) && $this->cat_products) ? $this->cat_products : null,
        'id_category' => (int)$this->category->id,
        'id_category_parent' => (int)$this->category->id_parent,
        'return_category_name' => Tools::safeOutput($this->category->name),
        'path' => Tools::getPath($this->category->id),
        'add_prod_display' => Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
        'categorySize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('category')),
        'mediumSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('medium')),
        'thumbSceneSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('m_scene')),
        'homeSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('home')),
        'allow_oosp' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_OUT_OF_STOCK'),
        'comparator_max_item' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_COMPARATOR_MAX_ITEM'),
        'suppliers' => Supplier::getSuppliers(),
        'body_classes' => array($this->php_self.'-'.$this->category->id, $this->php_self.'-'.$this->category->link_rewrite)
    ));
}
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Another (cleaner - no overrides) way is to create a module that uses hook `displayOverrideTemplate` and serve a proper template.

```
public function hookDisplayOverrideTemplate($params) 
{
    $controller = $params['controller'];
    if ($controller->php_self != 'category') {
        return false;
    }

    $id_category = (int)Tools::getValue('id_category');
    if ($id_category == 3) {
        return 'path_to_tpl1.tpl';
    }
    else {
        return 'path_to_tpl2.tpl'; // or return false to use default template
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your category.tpl file and change the code like so (19 is the id of your custom category):

```
{if $category->id == "19"}

  \\ create in theme dir a file named category-19.tpl and add custom code in it 
  {include file="$tpl_dir./category-19.tpl"}

{else}

 \\ default category.tpl code

{/if}
```